# Passing a parameter to the method in each iteration of the loop

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uirepeat, graphicimage

I'm trying with each iteration of the loop to get the data to display.

*xhtml*

```
...
<ui:repeat var="cat" value="${animalBean.listCat}">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{animalBean.getImage(cat)}"/>                                               
</ui:repeat>
...
```

*AnimalBean*

```
...
private List<Cat> listCat;
private StreamedContent image;
// getters + setters

public StreamedContent getImage(Cat c) {
    // Here c is null
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(c.getPhoto1()));
}
...
```

Is it possible to somehow pass a parameter to the method so that at each iteration to perform a method which obtains the data?

Comment: I checked that topic. Unfortunately, it did not help in my case...

Comment: If it doesn't work then you did something wrong. Try once again based on kickoff example given in the answer while putting aside your current code.